# Get new addresses of token holders for a ERC20 token

Tags: wallets

I am looking for the number of token holders (addresses) in an ERC20 token in two different times, in order to observe how many new token holders were created for that ERC20 token.

I spend many time among the ehtherscan api , ethplorer api and others but cannot find a method to retrieve that data. Even though https://etherscan.io/ have the data of token holders, my goal is to observe new token holders by ERC20 token in a month for example.

Regards, 
Nicolás

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can filter all the `Transfer()` events originated in the token contract between two blocks, ie `startBlock` and `endBlock`. The "to" field of the event is the recipient, to get a list of new recipients you have to remove all the recipients that owned toekns previous to the startBlock.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a standalone tool which collects ERC-20 token holders and transactions to SQLite database

- Take a token contract address
- Iterate over all `Transfer` events for token using `eth_getLogs` JSON-RPC API
- Build a local database of these events
- Allow you to use SQL to query any account balance on any point of time (block num)

The tool maintains a local SQLite database. The subsequent command runs scan the new blocks, since last run, and write the new transactions to the database. Exporting this from SQL based on a timestamp should be quite easy.

[You can find the command line application execution example how to build the token holder database here](https://docs.tokenmarket.net/erc-20-holders.html)

[The core Python logic is here](https://github.com/TokenMarketNet/sto/blob/master/sto/ethereum/scanner.py).

There are some quirks here and there: for example detecting mint / creation event for some tokens is not straightforward. Thus, you will may negative balance on the account receiving initial total supply if you rely on `Transfer` event only.